# c# : passing dataTable to stored procedure: column order issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which accepts a **User defined table type** called `SeasonTable` which looks like this:

**SeasonTable**

```
    [SeasonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SeasonName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Month] [int] NULL, 
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL
```

Stored procedure is like as shown below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[udpTest] 
(
    @STable dbo.SeasonTable READONLY
)   
AS
BEGIN
SELECT [SeasonName] as SeasonName,[SeasonId],[Month],[IsDeleted] 
    FROM @AdminBillingSeasonsTable
END
```

When I call this from C# application

```
private DataTable TestCreateDataTable()
{
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("SeasonName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SeasonId", typeof(int));                
            dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("IsDeleted", typeof(bool));
            dt.Rows.Add("season1",1, 4,  false);
            dt.Rows.Add("season2",2, 9, false);
            dt.Rows.Add("season3",3, 11,  false);
            return dt;
}
```

When I use the above table as param to SP from C# app it is throwing error:

> unable to convert "season1" to int.

Does this mean the column order in C# app should be same as the column order in SQL?

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried switching your Column sequence(SeasonId then SeasonName) in dt ??

Comment: @yogi ya after switching it worked fine.!!!!

Comment: @yogi maybe need to add that as the answer: so people know it's been answered

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try Switching your column sequence something like this

```
 private DataTable TestCreateDataTable()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.Add("SeasonId", typeof(int));     // seasonId and then
                dt.Columns.Add("SeasonName", typeof(string)); // seasonName
                dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("IsDeleted", typeof(bool));
                dt.Rows.Add("season1",1, 4,  false);
                dt.Rows.Add("season2",2, 9, false);
                dt.Rows.Add("season3",3, 11,  false);
                return dt;
            }
```

Comment: Actually `User defined table type` excepts columns in that format only in which they have been created in SQL, we can't juggle them, at least I don't know how to do that, So its better to keep sequence correct & synchronize.

Comment: I'm automatically generating my data tables for this and I can confirm that as described here, SQL Server ignores the table column names and types and relies only on the order of them when a Stored Proc gets a table parameter. So somewhere you have to order those columns.

Comment: @philw same experience here, except it doesnt *ignore* *type*. It tries to convert the type if there exist a conversion. The name is ignored yes.

Comment: Do we have solution for automatically generating my data tables? Index will not match for sure, then what is the best way?

Comment: we can try this code for dynamic table creation
DataTable table = new DataTable();

// Declare a variable of the desired table type to produce a result set with it's schema.
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("DECLARE @tableType dbo.UserDefindTableType 
                                             SELECT * FROM @tableType", ConnectionString);

// Sets the DataTable schema to match dbo.UserDefindTableType .
adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);

Comment: This is not a very good solution, ADO.NET should handle that.